# Hover, onClick functionalities not working on dynamically added content(button) in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

I am taking a URL input and shortening it using an API and adding this shortened URL with a copy button dynamically to the DOM so that the user gets the shortened URL but when I added the logic for copying the URL in react it didn't work, I found that even simple console.log statement is not working on button click for this dynamically added button

```
import React from "react";
import Button from "./Button";
import { useState } from "react";

function LoadShortenUrl(props){

    const [copyText, setCopyText] = useState("");
    const [buttonText, setButtonText] = useState("Copy");

    function handleButtonText() {
        console.log("Clicked");
        setButtonText("Copied");
    } 

    const handleCopy = () => {
        navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText)
        alert("Text Copied");
        console.log("Text Copied");
    };

    const links = Array.from({ length: props.ogLink.length }, (_, i) => (
        <div className="display-url">
            <p key={i}>
                {props.ogLink[i]} 
            </p>
            <a className="shorten-link-position" href={props.shortenLink[i]}>{props.shortenLink[i]}</a>
            <Button OnClick={handleButtonText} buttonText="Copy" className="submitButton"></Button>
        </div>
      ));

    return (
        <>
        {links}
        </>
    )
}

export default LoadShortenUrl;
```

This is the component code I am calling the `handleButtonText` function onClick for this button the length of the array will be 0 first and as soon as the user submits url it will loop through this code and add the elements to the DOM.

Answer (score -1):

```
try this


 ***<Button onClick={handleButtonText} buttonText="Copy" className="submitButton"></Button>***
```

write a proper way code like camelCase convention **it's onClick not a OnClick**

Comment: Hi I have created a  Button component and OnClick is a prop that I am passing inside the button component the I have used the proper onClick listener and it is working fine for other places.

Comment: HTML elements and attributes are case-insensitive.